# How to deploy multiple arm templates for logic apps..by selecting the templates dynamically at runtime using devops pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-logic-apps, cd

How to deploy multiple arm templates for logic apps by selecting the templates dynamically at runtime using devops pipelines. Should Build only checked in arm templates and deploy all the templates at a time based on the build artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

One way is as below:

1. Name your Logic App ARM templates as `<ProjectName>.<LogicAppName>.json` and parameters file as `<ProjectName>.<LogicAppName>.param.json`
2. Add all the Logic App templates in a folder in your build artifact.
3. In Release pipeline, add a variable named `LogicAppNames` with the comma separated names' list of `<LogicAppName>` values in Pipeline variables which can be scoped to Release.
4. Add an Agent Job with `Multi-Configuration` as `Parallelism` and value of `multipliers` as `LogicAppNames` and `maximum number of agents` as per your build agents' availability.
5. Add a `ARM Template deployment task` like below:

> ```
> -  task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3   
>     displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'   
>     inputs:
>     azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Visual Studio Enterprise (****)'
>     subscriptionId: '********************************'
>     resourceGroupName: 'resourceGroup'
>     location: 'West US'
>     csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BuildArtifactName/templates/<ProjectName>.$(LogicAppNames).json'
>     csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BuildArtifactName/templates/<ProjectName>.$(LogicAppNames).param.json'
> ```